# Advice for Snake Game in C++

Tags: c++, console

I want just to ask you something. I don't expect any code from you. I want to make a Snake Game. My idea is to make an array and control the snake with the **GetAsyncKeyState()** function. I have not decided yet how to move the snake but I'm considering the idea to use linked list to hold the coords of the snake's body in the array.

I have two questions:
1. Do you like my idea to use linked list?
2. I need to clear the console somehow and output the table again. But if I use **system("CLS")**, the screen is blinking. Is there a better way to clear the console without blinking?

Any other ideas will be appreciated. :)

Here is my code for now.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int matrix[20][40];
void FillMatrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
void Show()
    {
        COORD pos = {0, 0};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(cout, pos);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
                    {
                        if(i == 0 || j == 0 || i == 19 || j == 39) cout << "#";
                        else if(matrix[i][j] == 0) cout << " ";
                        else cout << ".";
                    }
                cout << endl;
            }
    }
void Change(int i, int j)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
int main()
    {
        FillMatrix();
        int x, y;
        x = 4;
        y = 4;
        while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
            {
                Sleep(100);
                //system("cls");
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) 
                    {
                        y = y-1;
                        Change(x, y);
                    }
                else 
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) 
                        {
                            x = x-1;
                            Change(x, y);
                        }
                else 
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) 
                        {
                            y = y+1;
                            Change(x, y);
                        }
                else 
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) 
                        {
                            x = x+1;
                            Change(x, y);
                        }
                Show();
            }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I haven't written much code yet. First, I want to get the concept of the task before writing the code. And again - I don't expect any code from you.

Comment: I don't particularly like the idea of you using any *specific* data structure until you can defend your choice.  So tell us why you want to use a list.

Comment: Whether or not you expect code from anyone is irrelevant.  This is a bad question for several reasons.  First, it's two questions wrapped in one.  Second, the first question is opinion based (and so even by itself, it remains a bad question).  Third, the second question may serve as a good StackOverflow question... but you haven't supplied any relevant code for us to try to recreate the error or spot it for ourselves without having to recreate it.

Comment: @nhgrif: Nonsense - it's plainly obvious why the screen would blink when graphics are implemented on a console in this way. This question is not a code-level but a design-level question, so your demands for code ring particularly hollow ... and not to mention _rude_. That's particularly interesting considering your profile identifies you not as a professional, but a "student, wanting to become professional programmer".

Comment: If you're thinking of just clearing the screen every time and then just `std::cout`ing the entire game area, this is a crazy idea. You'll need to use a proper terminal handling library, in which case you'll use whatever screen clearing facilities come with that (in reality, you won't, you'll just write a new character at the new head of the snake, and overwrite the old location of the tail with a space, unless he's just eaten some food in which case you'll leave the old tail there.)

Comment: @nhgrif, ok, I get your point. I will be more careful next time.
Why I want to use linked list? I thought that I can put the coords of the snake's body in it and it till be easier to move the snake. But maybe it won't be the perfect idea. But I will figure it out. The biggest problem is how to clear the console and output the new table with the snake moved with one position in some direction without blinking.  I have two loop to output the array.

Comment: I would have reached for a GUI straight away.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: It's not sufficient to play with the characters: you have to remember where the snake is for collision detection reasons.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, which library do you recommend for a task like this? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't say anything about not needing to remember characters, but in any case, you often don't have to remember them, because you can typically just read whatever character is currently in the location you're about to move to. Obviously if you're ever going to need to redraw the whole thing (after a CTRL-Z, for instance) then you need to remember them.

Comment: @SinanZikri: Depends on what platform you're on. `ncurses` would be the obvious answer for a UNIX-like platform.

Comment: @SinanZikri:  It doesn't sound to me like you have a legitimate reason for using a list.  If that's the case then I suggest you give your design some more thought and figure out what you need from the container you choose.  In the meantime I'd suggest using a `vector`, because that is the default I always recommend if you have no particular reason to select another container.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using Windows XP 32-bit, will ncurses help me?

Comment: @SinanZikri: I don't do much Windows work, but I don't think so. You can use the Windows console API, see Jerry Coffin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a linked list is almost always a poor idea. In this case, there seems to be *no* reason to even consider using one. The primary point in favor of using a linked list is when you need to insert or delete items in the middle of the list (and, to gain much, already have something  pointing to the specific place in the list where the insertion/deletion needs to take place).

Since you're apparently using Win32, I wouldn't clear the screen at all. Instead, I'd use `WriteConsoleOutput` to write your new output to the screen, overwriting whatever was previously there.

Although it's not a snake game *per se*, here's code to an implementation of John Conway's Game of Life using `WriteConsoleOutput` to produce the screen output. It also includes a `ClrScr` function to clear the screen, if you decide you really *must* do that (but you probably don't).

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>

#define     ROWS        50
#define     COLS        80

// The total number of generations is really double this number.
int generations = 1000;

int civ1[ROWS+2][COLS+2], civ2[ROWS+2][COLS+2];

CHAR_INFO disp[ROWS][COLS];
HANDLE console;
COORD size = { COLS, ROWS };
COORD src = { 0, 0};
SMALL_RECT  dest = { 0, 0, COLS, ROWS };

void ClrScrn(char attrib) {
    COORD pos = { 0, 0};
    DWORD written;
    unsigned size;

    size = ROWS * COLS;

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(console, ' ', size, pos, &written);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console, attrib, size, pos, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, pos);
}

void fill_edges(int civ1[ROWS+2][COLS+2]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i=1; i<=ROWS; ++i) {
        civ1[i][0] = civ1[i][COLS];
        civ1[i][COLS+1] = civ1[i][1];
    }
    for (j=1; j<=COLS; ++j) {
        civ1[0][j] = civ1[ROWS][j];
        civ1[ROWS+1][j] = civ1[1][j];
    }
    civ1[0][0] = civ1[ROWS][COLS];
    civ1[ROWS+1][COLS+1] = civ1[1][1];
    civ1[0][COLS+1] = civ1[ROWS][1];
    civ1[ROWS+1][0] = civ1[1][COLS];
}

void update_generation(int old_gen[ROWS+2][COLS+2],
                        int new_gen[ROWS+2][COLS+2])
{
    int i, j, count;

    for (i = 1; i <= ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= COLS; ++j)
        {
            count = old_gen[i - 1][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i - 1][j] +
                old_gen[i - 1][j + 1] +
                old_gen[i][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i][j + 1] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j - 1] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j] +
                old_gen[i + 1][j + 1];

            switch(count)
            {
            case 2:
                new_gen[i][j] = old_gen[i][j];
                break;

            case 3:
                new_gen[i][j] = 1;
                disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = '*';
                break;
            default:
                new_gen[i][j] = 0;
                disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    WriteConsoleOutput(console, (CHAR_INFO *)disp, size, src, &dest);
    fill_edges(new_gen);
}

void initialize(void)
{
    int i, j;

    ClrScrn(0x71);
    srand(((unsigned int)time(NULL))|1);

    for (i = 1; i <= ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= COLS; ++j)
        {
            civ1[i][j] = (int)(((__int64)rand()*2)/RAND_MAX);
            disp[i-1][j-1].Char.AsciiChar = civ1[i][j] ? '*' : ' ';
            disp[i-1][j-1].Attributes = 0x71;
        }
    }
    WriteConsoleOutput(console, (CHAR_INFO *)disp, size, src, &dest);
    fill_edges(civ1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;

    if ( argc != 1)
        generations = atoi(argv[1]);

    console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    initialize();
    for (i = 0; i <generations; ++i)
    {
        update_generation(civ1, civ2);
        update_generation(civ2, civ1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I would have chosen a linked list simply because the snake gets longer over time and a linked list makes this easy and with each piece of the body occupying a different cell would make sense.  A vector would need a complete reallocation every time it grows?  what would you chose?

Comment: @rfcoder89: A vector will *not* need a complete reallocation every time it grows (it typically requires reallocation only when the new size is more than 1.5x the old size, though that factor can vary). I'd probably use a vector, but might consider a deque. I still see *no* reason to consider a linked list. Note that you don't really need to keep track of every block in the snake either -- only the head, tail, and any turning points. More than a few dozen or so points is likely to be quite rare.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It grows from the front and the back. I'd settle on deque, but vector? No. [_edit: well okay, not "grows" from the back exactly...]_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There's no need for it to "grow" at the front at all. As noted in the answer, the vector doesn't need to hold every block, only the position of the front, back, and each turning point in the snake. Adding blocks to the front just means modifying the position of the "head" without changing the positions of the others; it doesn't require adding elements to the vector at all.

Comment: @Jerry: Two points and a deque of points, then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As I already said, I'd certainly at least consider a deque. OTOH, given that he's apparently developing for Windows, chances are pretty fair that he's using VC++ (and its implementation of deque is quite poor).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: thank you for that detail on vectors

Comment: @JerryCoffin: `(and its implementation of deque is quite poor)` where "deque" = "C++"

Comment: Well I considered my idea and realized that I don't need to store the whole body of the snake. I just need to delete the last part of the tail in every move. That should be much easier. Now the problem is only about the clearing of the console. @JerryCoffin, can you share a link with examples and more information about WriteConsoleOutput, because I couldn't find any :)

Comment: I have only one problem. When I use **WriteConsoleOutput(cout, pos);** (pos = {0, 0}), the output begins from the next line. It doesn't overwrite on the previous output. How can I make it to start outputing from the beginning of the console's window?

Comment: @SinanZikri: Impossible to guess what you'e done wrong without seeing the code. If you run the code above, you'll see it overwrites the existing content.

Comment: I posted my code. Can you check it?

Comment: @SinanZikri: As far as I can see, it doesn't use `WriteConsoleOutput` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Until you can prove otherwise with some rationalisation, it sounds like you've chosen a linked list because you've heard the name before.

As for screen blinking, terminals don't double buffer so that's just the way it is, until you use a library like `ncurses` to move the cursor around *overwriting positions* rather than repeatedly cleaning the screen and starting from scratch.

Comment: Can you tell me does ncurses run on Windows XP 32-bit? :)

Comment: @Sinan: You tell me :)

Comment: Looks like it will not :/

Comment: Honestly, using terminal for this will kill you.